# Why did my reputation inexplicably go up by about 100?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

And when I add up the daily numbers they add up to 635 but my reputation shows as 740.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: You already have 704 reputation on Stack Overflow, so any account you create on the Stack Exchange network which uses the same credentials as that account, you will automatically get 100 free reputation to start you off (get you past some reputation limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting up another stack exchange user, on say superuser.com and linking the two gives you a boost first time you do it.

Answer (score 3):

You got 100 bonus points for associating your SO account (which is now done automatically) with a new account created on one of the Stack Exchange sites (in your case, [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/37147/)).

You can see changes to your reputation (including bonuses), by accessing the reputation page:
https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

You should see at the very top, something like:

```
total votes: X
-- bonuses   (100)  <- THIS
```

Answer (score 2):

You created an [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/37147/agks-mehx) account today. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with **200** or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting **+100** reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in